# Hide indicator scroll in PDFKit

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

This is my PDFView config. I want to show PDF viewer with horizontal scroll, show single page.

But PDFView show the scroll indicator and it is not correct. I want to hide scroll indicator. My question is how to hide it or how to make its scroll position correct?

[image: Horizontal scroll indicator visible at bottom of screen]

```
pdfView.autoScales = true
pdfView.displaysPageBreaks = true
pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
pdfView.minScaleFactor = 1
pdfView.document = pdfDocument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since PDFview is not giving access to its scrolling elements,  the trick of accessing subviews of pdfview may work for you.

Chain of subviews when printed on console looks like:

```
(lldb) po pdfView.subviews
▿ 1 element
    - 0 : <_UIPageViewControllerContentView: 0x7fec7411d9f0; frame = (0 0; 414 808); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001b33720>>

(lldb) po pdfView.subviews.first?.subviews.first
▿ Optional<UIView>
  - some : <_UIQueuingScrollView: 0x7fec7483aa00; frame = (0 0; 414 736); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000015153e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600001b33740>; contentOffset: {414, 0}; contentSize: {1242, 736}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>

(lldb)
```

So based on this, I have tested below code and it worked at my end. Try with code:

```
    let pdfScrollView = pdfView.subviews.first?.subviews.first as? UIScrollView
    pdfScrollView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false  // if pdf view scroll direction is horizontal
    pdfScrollView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false // if pdf view scroll direction is vertical
```

**Edit:**

The view's hierarchy is been updated and scrollView is not at the first place
Please refer answer from @Deepansh for getting scrollView object:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77080309/2677551

Comment: not working in my case

Comment: iterate through all subviews to find the scrollview, it is not in the first subview

Comment: @JagveerSingh the hierarchy is been updated for views please refer answer from Deepansh and refer updated solutions below

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better solution to find `UIScrollView` of subviews:

It's tested on SwiftUI 2, 3 and working well.

```
UIViewRepresentable > makeUIView function
```

Finding UIScrollView and modifications:

```
let pdfView = PDFView()    
for view in pdfView.subviews {
    if let scrollView = findUIScrollView(of: view) {
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    }
}
    
func findUIScrollView(of uiView: UIView) -> UIScrollView? {
    if let scrollView = uiView as? UIScrollView {
        return scrollView
    }
        
    for view in uiView.subviews {
       if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
           return scrollView
        }
            
        if !view.subviews.isEmpty {
            return findUIScrollView(of: view)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented an extension and then use like this, please have a look.

```
import Foundation
import PDFKit

extension PDFView {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
        guard let pageViewControllerContentView = subviews.first else { return nil }
        for view in pageViewControllerContentView.subviews {
            guard let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView else { continue }
            return scrollView
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

and then I use

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    pdfView.scrollView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    pdfView.scrollView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
}
```

Another more straightforward way is: before your app starts showing an element with `PDFView` (for example `UIViewController`) you need to set this

```
UIScrollView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
UIScrollView.appearance().showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

and it will work for you.
then when you'll need to dismiss `UIViewController` or another element with the `PDView`, you can return back previous settings

```
UIScrollView.appearance().showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
UIScrollView.appearance().showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The UIScrollView is not inside the first subview anymore (as mentioned in previous answers), so iterate through all subviews to find the UIScrollView

```
extension PDFView {   
    func hideScrollViewIndicator(){
        for subview in subviews {
            if let scrollView = subview as? UIScrollView {
                scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
                scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
pdfView.hideScrollViewIndicator()
```